Use Gaussian elimination with back substitution and two-digit
Use Gaussian elimination with back substitution and two-digit rounding arithmetic to solve the following systems. Do not rearrange the equations. (the exact solution of the system is $x_1=1\\ x_2=−1 \\ x_3=3$.
$4x_1 - x_2 + x_3 =8 \\
2x_1 + 5x_2 + 2x_3 =3\\
x_1 + 2x_2 +4x_3 = 11$
The expanded matrix of the system is:
$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
4&-1&1&8\\
2&5&2&3\\
1&2&4&11\\\end{array}\right)$
To make Gaussian zeros in the first column we have to:

From the second row, subtract half of the first.
From the third row subtract a quarter of the first.

What you have to keep in mind is that they say you round to two digits. So:

Half of the first row is $2\quad -0.5\quad 0.5\quad 4$ and when subtracting from the second this is $0\quad 5.5\quad 1.5\quad -1$.

The fourth part of the first row is $1 \quad -0.25 \quad 0.25\quad 2$. To subtract it from the third you have to round using only two significant figures:


$1-1=0$
$2-(-0.25)=2.25\approx 2.3$
$4-0.25=3.75\approx 3.8$
$11-2=9$
After this first step it would be:
$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
4&-1&1&8\\
0&5.5&1.5&-1\\
0&2.3&3.8&9\\\end{array}\right)$
can you help me? I can't continue, I don't understand the backward substitution thing

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & -1 & 1 & 8 \\
2 & 5 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 4 & 11 \\
\end{array}
\right] \overset{R_3 = 2R_3 - R_2}{\longrightarrow} \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & -1 & 1 & 8 \\
2 & 5 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & -1 & 6 & 19 \\
\end{array}
\right] \overset{R_2 = 2 R_2 - R_1}{\longrightarrow} \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & -1 & 1 & 8 \\
0 & 11 & 3 & -2 \\
0 & -1 & 6 & 19 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
$$
\overset{R_2 = R_2 / 11}{\longrightarrow} \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & -1 & 1 & 8 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{11} & \frac{-2}{11} \\
0 & -1 & 6 & 19 \\
\end{array}
\right] \overset{R_3 = R_3 + R_2}{\longrightarrow} \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & -1 & 1 & 8 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{11} & -\frac{2}{11} \\
0 & 0 & \frac{69}{11} & \frac{207}{11} \\
\end{array}
\right] \overset{R_3 = 11R_3 / 69}{\longrightarrow} \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
4 & -1 & 1 & 8 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{11} & -\frac{2}{11} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
$$
\overset{R_1 = R_1 / 4}{\longrightarrow} \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 2 \\
0 & 1 & \frac{3}{11} & -\frac{2}{11} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
We now have the system of equations
\begin{align}
x_1 - \frac{1}{4} x_2 + \frac{1}{4} x_3 &= 2 \\
x_2 + \frac{3}{11} x_3 &= -\frac{2}{11} \\
x_3 &= 3 \\
\end{align}
and we can perform backsubstitution.
We know $x_3$ so we substitute this into the second equation and solve for $x_2$. And then we substitute $x_2$ and $x_3$ into the first equation to solve for $x_1$.
